# Connect Parse.com Database to Tableau

Tags: parse-platform, tableau-api

Has anyone connected parse.com to Tableau desktop before?

How did you go about it?

I've been googling instructions to no avail.  Any guidance and/or links to resources greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up learning node.js to manipulate data and create .csv tables that I can load up straight into tableau.

Works fine.